# Angular does provider dependency order matter?

Tags: angular

just noticed a strange behaviour on our angular project. Below you can find an app provider, which should be responsible to load specific information in the right order.

AuthService.initialize returns an observable, which concatMaps the user profile getter. The strange thing is, if I flip the deps array from [auth,organization,organizationPermission] to [organization, organizationPermission, auth] the organization initializer doesn't have a loaded profile. In my opinion, that makes no sense regarding the documentation, as this says, that the dependecies, that are injected are loaded as needed. Can someone explain this behaviour?

```
// APP PROVIDER
export const appProviderFactory = (
  authService: AuthService,
  organizationService: OrganizationService,
  organizationPermissionService: OrganizationPermissionService
) => {
  return (): Observable<any> => {
    return authService.initialize().pipe(
      concatMap(() => organizationPermissionService.initialize()),
      concatMap(() => organizationService.initialize())
    );
  };
};

export const appProvider = {
  provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
  useFactory: appProviderFactory,
  deps: [OrganizationService, OrganizationPermissionService, AuthService],
  multi: true
};
```

Note: The functions in my services are all called initialize, but I can't see anything that says, that this is reserved and automatically loaded.

That the order of the injected dependencies doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1):

your custom piece of code makes the order important

```
return authService.initialize().pipe(
  concatMap(() => organizationPermissionService.initialize()),
  concatMap(() => organizationService.initialize())
);
```

i.e. serviceA.initialize() then serviceB.initialize() then serviceC.initialize(), and considering that you've said something is not working properly, serviceB.initialize most probably depends on serviceA.initialize().

when you change the order of dependencies, different order of arguments are passed (with wrong types) in your factory. and, because of the order change the order is broken

Comment: Ahhhhh, oh my god. That was a new definition of stupidity... Sorry for bothering.